# Replace a value with regular expressions in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a value assigned to variable, trying to add this value to another varible inside some regular expressions.

```
$displayName= "revison"

$updateddisplayName = "updateddisplayName = "${$displayName}""

Write-Host "$updateddisplayName"
```

I am able to get the variable value with below but not getting expected result. Tried with some different regular expressions as well.

```
$updateddisplayName = "updateddisplayName = $displayName"
```

I tried with replace but looks use case of Regex is almost same so did not worked.

```
(Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot/text.txt -Raw) -Replace 'setDisplayName.*', 'updateddisplayName = "${$displayName}"' | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot/text.txt
```

OutPut expected is **updateddisplayName = "${revison}"**

Comment: `${revison}` is valid variable and variables can expand in `"`, you need to use `'` (single quotes) instead `$updateddisplayName = 'updateddisplayName = "${$displayName}"'`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This was not working. the out put of this is updateddisplayName = "${$displayName}" but I am looking for an out put with displayname value as well like updateddisplayName = "${revison}"

Comment: Using concatenation of single-quoted strings might be more readable and avoids the escaping hassles: `"$updateddisplayName = 'updateddisplayName = "${' + $displayName + '}"'`

Comment: So you actually want to expand the value of `$displayName` while also keeping `${` and `}` if so then Mathias's answer solves that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` double-quotes, either by doubling them or with a backtick, and then you need to escape the first `$` - otherwise PowerShell will see `${$displayName}` and attempt to resolve and expand the value of a variable with the literal name `$displayName`:

```
$displayName= "revison"

$updateddisplayName = "updateddisplayName = ""`${$displayName}"""
```