# Loop through each line of a text file, split and get the required values and use them in a template

Tags: powershell

I have a file with below content

```
build( "job1", parameter1: value1, parameter2: value2 )

build( "job2", parameter3: value3, parameter4: value4, parameter5: value5 )

build( "job3", parameter6: value6, parameter7: value7, parameter8: value8,  parameter9: value9 )
```

Note: Jobs section is common but Parameters may increase or decrease for each item

I want to split each string which are comma separated and get the required values and use them in a template

I have tried this

```
$file = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot/dslreading.txt

foreach ($buildJob in $file ) {

    # I am able to get the Jobname using below one but in every loop i am getting same value as job1 only.
    $jobName = (Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot/dslreading.txt -Raw).Split('"')[1]
    
    # I am not able to get each parameter and the respective value of that parameter
    #$parameters = (Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot/dslreading.txt -Raw).Split(",")

    #Note: Based on number of parameters i have to increase or decrese the parameters as well
    $jobs = "build job: '$jobName', parameters: [string(name: '$parameter1', value: ""${value}""), string(name: 'parameter2', value: ""${value}"")]"
    Write-Host "$jobs"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you, it uses regex instead of splitting. It's not clear exactly how the output should look but I presume, by [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76713781/replace-a-value-with-regular-expressions-in-powershell), that the parameter values should be wrapped in `${ }` like this:

```
build job: 'job1', parameters: [string(name: 'parameter1', value: "${value1}"), string(name: 'parameter2', value: "${value2}")]
build job: 'job2', parameters: [string(name: 'parameter3', value: "${value3}"), string(name: 'parameter4', value: "${value4}"), string(name: 'parameter5', value: "${value5}")]
build job: 'job3', parameters: [string(name: 'parameter6', value: "${value6}"), string(name: 'parameter7', value: "${value7}"), string(name: 'parameter8', value: "${value8}"), string(name: 'parameter9', value: "${value9}")]
```

The code you can try:

```bash
$teststrings = Get-Content path\to\file.txt

$re = [regex]::new(
    '(?<=build\()\s*"(?<jobname>[^""]+)"(?:,\s*(?<paramname>\w+)\s*:\s*(?<paramvalue>\w+))+',
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions] 'Compiled, IgnoreCase')

foreach ($string in $teststrings) {
    $match = $re.Match($string)

    if (-not $match.Success) {
        continue
    }

    $params = @($match.Groups['paramname'].Captures.Value)
    $values = @($match.Groups['paramvalue'].Captures.Value)

    $groups = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $params.Count; $i++) {
        "string(name: '{0}', value: ""`${{{1}}}"")" -f $params[$i], $values[$i]
    }

    "build job: '{0}', parameters: [{1}]" -f $match.Groups['jobname'].Value, ($groups -join ', ')
}
```

And the regex details: https://regex101.com/r/ITaXQn/1.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to read the content from a file instead of having hardcoded values in $teststrings?

Comment: @Hemanth of course, just change to `$teststrings = Get-Content path\to\thefile` :)

Comment: If there is only one parameter then the code is not working as expected. Below is the result with single parameter Input: build( "job1", parameter1: value1 ) Output: build job: 'job1', parameters: [string(name: 'p', value: "${v}")]. Any fix for this?

Comment: @Hemanth my bad, i was missing `@( ... )` in the captures. See edit

Comment: Need one small improvement, If a value is URL and it is with in " ", the code is not working. build("job4", parameter9: "abc-1.xyz.com", parameter10: value10 )