# Issue with set-content when file is in System.IO.StreamReader

Tags: powershell

I have a file with multiple lines, in some lines I need to replace with some other value. The value I am getting from another function.

```
some content related to file
some content related to file
some content related to file
build( "job2", parameter3: value3, parameter4: value4, parameter5: value5 )
some content related to file
some content related to file
build( "job1", parameter1: value1 )
some content related to file
some content related to file
some content related to file
build( "job3", parameter6: value6, parameter7: value7, parameter8: 
value8,  parameter9: value9 )
some content related to file
some content related to file
```

I have tried below, but its failing with Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'text.txt' because it is being used by another process

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("$PSScriptRoot/text.txt")

$lines = @()

if ($file -ne $null) {
while (!$file.EndOfStream) {
    $line = $file.ReadLine()
    foreach ($build in $line) {
    if ($build.Contains("build(")) {
        Write-host "$build"
        (Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot/text.txt -Raw) -Replace 'build', "build Job" | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot/text.txt
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Santiago. On extension to your previous answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76717578/loop-through-each-line-of-a-text-file-split-and-get-the-required-values-and-use/76717709?noredirect=1#comment135259919_76717709), the out put lines I need to write them back to same file from which I am reading

Comment: why are you using a StreamReader to read the file content and then using Get-Content again? StreamReader shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be much simpler, there is no need for `StreamReader` in this case:

```bash
$path = "$PSScriptRoot/text.txt"
if (Test-Path $path) {
    $content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $path -Raw
    # `.Contains` is case sensitive
    # you can use `-match 'build\('` for case insensitive
    if ($content.Contains('build(')) {
        $content -replace 'build', 'build Job' |
            Set-Content $path
    }
}
```